# Flutter Material 3 Changed colors, and fonts

Tags: flutter, material3, flutter-material

So I just decided to give Material 3 a shot in Flutter and it changed a whole lot of colors, and fonts etc.

I knew certain things would look different like more rounded corners on my cards but I wasn't expecting all the fonts and card colors to change. I literally just added the `useMaterial3: true,` to the code below:

```
child: MaterialApp(
          debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
          routes: appRoutes,
          theme: ThemeData(
            useMaterial3: true,
            scaffoldBackgroundColor: const Color(0xFF2b8293),
          ),
          home: const CheckLogin(),
        ),
```

Here is an example of what has changed with before and after pictures:

[image]

[image]

Anyway to change the default card color, and title fonts so I do not have to change them in every view in the app one by one?

Also odd to see the vertical 3 dot icon changed to dark while the search Icon did not. Thanks!

Comment: you can try to override the themeData on MaterialApp

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Material 3 uses dynamic colors, you can override the theme using the `colorScheme` inside the `ThemeData` and tweak the colors there. Then, you can go to the widgets in you app and use `Theme.of(context).colorScheme` and then `.primary` or whatever you wish.

To know more about the Material 3 in Flutter you can check https://m3.material.io/develop/flutter

Answer (score 6):

Whenever you face color issue in material3 just use  **surfaceTintColor** propert inside the widget.

*surfaceTintColor: Colors.customColor*

Answer (score 5):

You can override the default theme on materialApp.

```dart
theme: ThemeData(
  useMaterial3: true,
  scaffoldBackgroundColor: const Color(0xFF2b8293),
  appBarTheme: AppBarTheme(
    titleTextStyle: TextStyle(...),
    iconTheme: IconThemeData(
      ...
    )
  )
),
```

Comment: Is there documentation some place that shows what each thing I would need to override is? 

For example what would the Card background color be?

Comment: You can read the [ThemeData](https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/design/themes)  to explore about it

Comment: No it does not. It just sets background color for scaffold.

Comment: @n.podbielski it would be easier for me if you ask a new question with [minimal-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) what exactly went wrong for your case

Comment: WDYM: it is in the name of the property 'scaffoldBGcolor'. Op asked about color for whole theme.

Comment: It is possible I did not get very well,  but as for the image mark&  last text *Anyway to change the default card color, and title fonts so I do not have to change them in every view in the app one by one?Also odd to see the vertical 3 dot icon changed...* I've guess to guess which can be wrong now that I was focused on theses.